# How to read json list in flask template

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask, jinja2

I am new to flask and python and I am trying to display the json list which I am getting from python,
this is the python

```
lista = []
    for msg in listOfData:
        dicta= {
            "a": msg[0],
            "b": msg[1],
            "c": msg[2],
            "d": msg[3],
        }
        lista.append(dicta)
    return render_template('page.html', jsnObj=json.dumps(lista ))
```

and here is the template:

```
<script>
  var tmpStr = '{{jsnObj | safe}}';
  var newStr = tmpStr.substring(1, tmpStr.length-1); //remove list square brackets
  var myJson = JSON.stringify(newStr);
  myJson = myJson.replace(/\\/g, ""); //remove slashes
  $('#paragraph').text(myJson);
</script>
```

The thing is that I need to loop on the json and get every key value separated like the normal way, so i want to be able to do the following:

```
{% for j in jsnObj %}
  {{j['a']}}
{% endfor %}
```

I keep getting json as string and can't use its keys's values, 
Note( I tried to use jsonify but then I couldn't render the template at the same time.)

Comment: why are you removing square brackets and slashes ?

Comment: @AbhishekKulkarni because I wanted to get a simple json and I thought I could access its keys just by key name in this case. so instead of ```[{\'a'\: 'b'}]``` I get ```{'a':'b'}```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below :

```
lista = []
for msg in listOfData:
    dicta= {
        "a": msg[0],
        "b": msg[1],
        "c": msg[2],
        "d": msg[3],
    }
    lista.append(dicta)
return render_template('page.html', jsnObj=lista)   # ---- No need for json.dumps here
```

and in your html do this :

```
{% for j in jsnObj %}
  {{j['a']}}
{% endfor %}
```

In your script directly use :

```
<script>
  var myJson = '{{jsnObj}}';
  $('#paragraph').text(JSON.stringify(myJson));
</script>
```

Comment: I must convert it to json in python before passing it, That's why I am stuck, All data passed between frontend/backend must be in json